# How to blacklist an IP address/domain in Nginx server block

Tags: nginx

I am trying to blacklist some bots that are hitting one of my sites. The bot comes from `paymentverificatiion.com` << notice two "i"s on "verification". I first found the IP address by doing `nslookup paymentverificatiion.com` which returns:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   paymentverificatiion.com
Address: 143.198.76.27
```

I then tried putting a `deny` statement in each location block, but that did not work. I then tried putting it in the server block, but that does not work:

```
upstream backend_server {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    deny 143.198.76.27;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location /api/ {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    
    location /static/ {      
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend_server$request_uri;
        ...omitted...
    }

    location /videos/ {
        ...omitted...
    }

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend_server$request_uri;
        ...omitted...
    }

    location /static/ {      
        alias /backend/assets/;
    }

    location /media/ {      
        alias /backend/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend_server$request_uri;
        ...omitted...
    }
}
```

How can I blacklist these bots?

Comment: Presuming your site is running nginx 1.9.2, http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_access_module.html

a) I see redirects from port 80 to the SSL urls on port 443. But I don't see anything denied in the 443/ssl section. 

b) Could you post some more information about where you've identified the bot as coming from a domain? If it's in the nginx log file it could be good to see a few lines from that to give some more context.

c) Are you able to block your own IP address? It's not a solution but it would be a good way to test it.

Comment: a) I tried using the deny statement in the 443 section as well. b) the information is being emailed to me as a log from my django backend. It keeps telling me I may need to add the site to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. c) I will try.

Comment: Ok, yes, I can deny my own IP address. I receive `403 forbidden`

Comment: If you can deny your own IP address, then you should be able to block other IP addresses. But the bots might be coming from somewhere else or they even might be using IP address spoofing. Hard to say without seeing the bigger picture, i.e., access to the log files.